# Using RestTemplate - how to pass List or Array in parameter from client to server

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have a `List<Integer>` which I want to send to server in parameter, is there any way Spring provide support for this?

I have tried using following code,

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId={cartItemsId[]}", 
            HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class, ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(cartItemsId.toArray(new Integer[cartItemsId.size()])));
```

But it sends to server something like:

`http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId=%5BI@18275d8c`

And same issue happens if I use:

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId={cartItemsId[]}", 
            HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class, cartItemsId);
```

**OR**

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId={cartItemsId[]}", 
            HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class, cartItemsId.toArray(new Integer[cartItemsId.size()]));
```

Is there any way I can send this List or Array to server using parameters?

Comment: How do you expect it or want it to be sent?

Comment: Something like http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId=1,2,3,4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Construct a `String` by joining the elements of the `List<Integer>` and provide that as a uri variable.

```
String listOfIds = cartItemsId.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
restTemplate.exchange("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/api/cart-items?cartItemsId={ids}",
    HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class, listOfIds);
```